# UTF-8 characters messed up after POST request in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, post

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC.

I'm trying to make a POST request to a Controller with FormData. But, if I put Arabic letters in the FormData to send to the Controller, it receives it as question marks.

I tried changing the Content-Type but then nothing sends at all.

This is how I send the POST request:

```
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            window.location.href = 'Categories';
        }
    }

    xhr.open("POST", 'http://localhost:52320/api/Categories/Add', true);

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('CatName', txtCatName.value);
    fd.append('FileName', uploadFileName);

    xhr.send(fd);
```

and this is how I receive it in the Controller:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CategoriesController : Controller {

    [Route("Add")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(FormData formData)
    {
            if (formData != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            DataManager.Instance.AddCategory(formData.CatName, formData.FileName);

                return Ok();
            }

        return BadRequest();
    }

}

public class FormData
{
    public string CatName { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It may be browser problem, you can check in development tools, what is sent to the server as FormData allways uses UTF-8 encodig, or it may be ASP.NET configuration issue. Check if this helps: https://forums.asp.net/t/1636683.aspx?Form+post+encoding

Comment: _“it receives it as question marks”_ – How do you verify that? You will to make sure that whatever _displays_ the data for you also understands the encoding properly and is able to show those characters to you. For example, the Visual Studio debugger will probably show you the correct value; a console you print to might not.

Comment: _"But, if I put Arabic letters in the FormData to send to the Controller, it receives it as question marks."_ I tested your code and I didn't get the result you said , it worked well . Press F12 in the google chrome to check the Form Data of the request  in Network tab. Please show the screenshots of the data you passed and the result that you got in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was inserting into SQL, actually. I thought it had been enough to make the column NVARCHAR but apparently I had to use N before the string.

Thanks to everyone in the comments for helping me out! It was useful.